# Rails 3 - Routes error, confused because it worked before on my old laptop but now getting errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've running an app on rails 3.0.7 using Ruby 1.9.3 and before on my old dev laptop everything in my routes file was okay. After switching to a new computer I had to re bundle install my gemlist using the exact version of old gems. But when I try to boot my dev server I get errors with my routes file. Not sure why, can anyone tell me where this is going wrong>

Thanks a lot.

ERROR

```
/Users/iHal9000/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@rails3gp/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load': /Users/iHal9000/Desktop/gp_public_gp/config/routes.rb:67: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block (SyntaxError)
     resources :stores, :only => :index, do  #
                                           ^
/Users/iHal9000/Desktop/gp_public_gp/config/routes.rb:73: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
/Users/iHal9000/Desktop/gp_public_gp/config/routes.rb:76: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :users do
     member do
     get :following, :followers 
     end
     resources :posts, :only => :index
     resources :stores, :only => :index, do  #line 67
     resources :posts, :only => :index
     end
     resources :collections do
       resources :posts, :only => :index
     end
     resources :artists, :only => :index, do #line 73
     do resources :posts, :only => :index
     end
  end #line 76
```

Comment: try deleting the trailing commas on line 67 and 73: `resources :stores, :only => :index do`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@jjing** mentioned you have to remove those `trailing commas` at the lines **67** and **73** and also you have to edit the line **74** too to remove `do`.Try updating your `routes.rb` file to like this

```
resources :users do
     member do
     get :following, :followers 
     end

     resources :posts, :only => :index
     resources :stores, :only => :index do  #here remove ,
     resources :posts, :only => :index
     end

     resources :collections do
     resources :posts, :only => :index #here also remove ,
     end

     resources :artists, :only => :index do 
     resources :posts, :only => :index #here remove do
     end
  end
```

This should work!

Comment: @muistooshort Yup! Its a simple typographical error.May be i should point out the line where the OP did wrong.

Comment: this helped me a lot either way, been away from programming for a few after some family stuff and didn't know where the error was. Many thanks!